# Cannot deploy Cloud Service to Azure from Jenkins

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to set up deploying an Azure Cloud Service to Azure from Jenkins using PowerShell but when I try executing Get-AzureDeployment I get the error 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.'

I'm trying it from my local machine as well and get the same error. The script I'm running is:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile "C:\Temp\CloudFareABTPublishSettings.publishsettings"

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "CloudFare ABT Test"


[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls1 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3;
Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName "CloudFareJourneyService" -Slot "Production" -ErrorVariable b -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
if($b[0] -ne $null)
{
  $b[0] | fl * -force
}
```

The ouput I get from PowerShell is:

```
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS
                        secure channel.
                           at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                           at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                           at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.DeploymentOperationsExtensions.GetBySlot(IDeploymentOperations operations, String serviceName, DeploymentSlot
                        deploymentSlot)
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.ServiceManagementBaseCmdlet.ExecuteClientActionNewSM[TResult](Object input, String operationDescription, Func`1
                        action, Func`3 contextFactory)
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureDeployment], HttpRequestException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.GetAzureDeploymentCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\srichmond\Documents\CloudFare\Azure\TestingScripts.ps1: line 7
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
```

I've tried looking at the traffic in WireShark and I can see this sequence of messages:

```
Client Hello
Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
```

There's no sign of Client Finished or Server Finished messages, but I don't know whether this matters.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you not have certificates installed on your client machine for your azure instances?

Comment: No, because I'm getting the certificate from the .publishsettings file. That part seems to be working.

Comment: Hello, Did You manage to solve Your issue?